# Add an extra column to /my-account/subscriptions/ WooCommerce page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I did add a metadata to all my WooCommerce subscriptions. Now I would like to present it as a new column in the /my-account/subscriptions/ page.
Is that possible? How to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can print usermeta data by simply adding all subscription user IDs in to an array:

```
$user = get_all_user_id(); 

foreach ($user as $usr) {

echo $usr->user_login; // just type in here the metadata name you created
echo $usr->first_name;
echo $usr->last_name; 

}
```

`/my-account/subscriptions/` which page is it?